# pseudo element is overlapping the original one even with z-index

Tags: css, pseudo-element

Please, can anyone explain to me this: why the heck the `z-index` isn't working?

```css
html,body,div {margin:0;padding:0;}
.bz {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    background: #0f0;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.bz:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 8px;
    height: 25px;
    transform: rotate(315deg);
    background: #f00;
}
.bz:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 8px;
    height: 25px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    background: #00f;
}
```

```html
<div class="bz">
  
</div>
```

the pseudo elements shouldn't overlap the original one in this case, right?

I played with it a bit(dah!), and found out that the `z-index` does works correct on pseudo elements itself:

`:after`(`z-index: 0`) `>` `:before`(`z-index: 0`)

`:after`(`z-index: -1`) `<` `:before`(`z-index: 1`)

So what the heck is going on here?!

Comment: Please don't post your working code to 3rd party sites as those links can die over time. Always include the relevant code, right here in you question as a "code snippet".

Comment: Will do, thanks for editing it for me, Scott

Comment: try to remove `z-index` from `.bz`

Comment: omfg, patelarpan! :D ...magic! :D but I can't to use it tho, as I must have `z-index` on my `.bz`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is because of "stacking contexts". A stacking context is like a deck of cards, you can control the layering order within a single deck, but if you have two decks, the layering order of one doesn't affect the layering order of another. The pseudo-elements (`::before` and `::after`) are in a different stacking context from the main element itself and, as a result, the `z-index` of those pseudo-elements are not comparable to the `z-index` of the main element.

From **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context)**:

> Each stacking context is completely independent from its siblings:
>   **only descendant elements are considered when stacking is processed**.

By changing the HTML structure so that all the rendered elements are siblings to each other and descendants of a common parent, the `z-index` works as it should.

```css
#wrapper { 
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
}

.bz {
    display: block;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    background: #0f0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    z-index: 1; /* Not actually necessary because the other z-indexes now apply */
}

.red {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 8px;
    height: 25px;
    transform: rotate(315deg);
    background: #f00;
}
.blue {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 8px;
    height: 25px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    background: #00f;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <!-- Now, all the child elements are in the same stacking context. -->
  <div class="bz"></div>
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="blue"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh, wow... so, basically, once I'm in the same stacking contexts(such as div 4 and 5 in the example at MDN), I can't go back? I just tried the `z-index: -1` on them and indeed, they remain the same...

Comment: @jeranexu See updated answer. Yes, what is in one stacking context is completely separate (from a `z-index` standpoint) from another. You have to structure your HTML correctly for stacking contexts to apply properly.